# Finding All Positions Of A Character In A String

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to find all the index numbers of a character in a python string using a very basic skill set. For example if I have the string "Apples are totally awesome" and I want to find the places where 'a' is in the string.
My ideal output would be:

```
0
7
14
19
```

These are all the places in the string that an 'a' appears (I think)

This is the code I have so far:

```
sentence = input("Input a string: ")
for ch in sentence:
    x = sentence.find('o')


print(x)
```

Here I'm looking for 'o' instead of a. My thought process is that for each character in the string the find function will return the position of the 'o'. Since I don't know how long the input string will be necessarily I used a for loop. I'm able to find and print out the first instance of an 'o' but not all of them. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should iterate over characters using `for index, ch in enumerate(sentence)`; then a simple equality check will suffice to determine whether to print `index` or not.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Answer (score 8):

Using `enumerate` is the standard way to go. Although, you can take advantage of the speed of `str.find` for time-critical operations.

### Code

```
def find_all(s, c):
    idx = s.find(c)
    while idx != -1:
        yield idx
        idx = s.find(c, idx + 1)

print(*find_all('Apples are totally awesome', 'o')) # 12 23
```

I made the above return a generator for elegance and to account for very large strings. Put it can of course be casted to a `list` if need be.

### Benchmark

Here is a benchmark against a solution using `enumerate` and a list-comprehension. Both solutions have linear time-complexity, but `str.find` is significantly faster.

```
import timeit

def find_all_enumerate(s, c):
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if c == x]

print(
    'find_all:',
    timeit.timeit("list(find_all('Apples are totally awesome', 'o'))",
                  setup="from __main__ import find_all")
)

print(
    'find_all_enumerate:',
    timeit.timeit("find_all_enumerate('Apples are totally awesome', 'o')",
                  setup="from __main__ import find_all_enumerate")
)
```

### Output

```
find_all: 1.1554179692960915
find_all_enumerate: 1.9171753468076869
```

Comment: That is a great solution.

Comment: @StephenRauch Well, you pointed out in that direction in another comment, so you deserve some credit

Comment: Can you provide an actual algorithmic analysis that this will always be more efficient? Do you know how these functions are implemented? A single timeit test doesn't strike me as compelling evidence.

Comment: @udadub Both algorithms do a single traversal for a single characters. It just turns out find is done at the C level. This drops the overhead of assignation of indices and items, making it faster by a constant. Time complexity is the same.

Comment: @ubadub To add to that, str.find uses [Boyer-Moore](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L5) which is O(nm). Thus is linear for m=1, which is the case in this problem.

Comment: if c == x not if if c == 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

Use you a list comprehension for great good:

```
[ind for ind, ch in enumerate(sentence) if ch.lower() == 'a']
```

will return a list of all the numbers you want. Print as desired.

And I assumed, based on your example, you don't care about case, hence the lower() function call. Using Python 3's asterisk splat operator (*) you could do all of this as a one liner; but that I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good spot for *enumerate*, it allows us to get the `index and item` when we loop, so if we match the `item` we can have the corresponding `index`, also its helpful to use `.lower()` to avoid issues with matching cases

```
s = 'Apples are totally awesome'

l = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(s.lower()) if 'o' in item]
```

Extended loop:

```
l = []
for idx, item in enumerate(s.lower()):
    if 'o' in item:
        l.append(idx)
```

> ```
> /python/stack$ python3.7 sum.py 
> [12, 23]
> ```

Comment: You really should consider using [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Comment: @StephenRauch find only finds the first occurence

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, find has a start, which allows you to find the next one.

Comment: Stephen, can you clarify why you suggest using find instead of enumerate?

Comment: OMG! I'm sorry this is the happiest day I've had in a long time, I have to rant, I just hit 1k rep, I know to some its meaningless, but my life really hit a rut this last couple months, prob worst in my 29 years, I decided to learn programming 33 days ago and I fell in love with Stack and just learning and this was such a goal for me again I know its nothing to you guys but for me its a ray of light, thank you all for everything its been a blessing learning from all of you <3

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use the `find` method in the following way

```
y="Apples are totally awesome"
    b=0
    for i in range (y.count(o)):
        a=y.find('o' , b)
        print(a)
        b=a+1
    #Returns all the positions of o
```

Comment: Please add some clear explanations of what  you are trying to achieve. Maybe an input and an output example.